# Wrong header subdir when cross-compiling for ARM

Tags: c, linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross-compile an application (tvheadend) for ARM (raspberry pi 2), using a x64 machine and [this](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools) toolchain.

I am using the following command line to configure the compilation:
`./configure --arch=arm-linux-gnueabihf --cc=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --disable-avahi --release --cflags=-DOPENSSL_USE_DEPRECATED` and then I just `make`.

The problem happens during the compilation of the source file `src/utils.c`: such file includes `string.h`, which is correctly selected from the toolchain include directory (let's say `ARMTOOLCHAIN/usr/include`), but then `string2.h`, which is inside `ARMTOOLCHAIN/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits`, is selected from the system directory, instead of `ARMTOOLCHAIN/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits`.

```
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h:35:0,
                 from ARMTOOLCHAIN/usr/include/endian.h:61,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string2.h:51,
                 from ARMTOOLCHAIN/usr/include/string.h:637,
                 from src/utils.c:21:
src/utils.c: In function ‘sbuf_put_be16’:
src/utils.c:397:9: error: invalid 'asm': invalid operand for code 'w'
   u16 = htons(u16);
         ^
```

The problem is that the compiler does not search inside `ARMTOOLCHAIN/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf` for the `bits` subdir. I tried to specify `-IARMTOOLCHAIN/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf` as an option, and to create a symlink to `bits` inside `ARMTOOLCHAIN/usr/include` (so to avoid `arm-linux-gnueabihf`), but none of these works.

Comment: Show the full error please. And the compiler invocation. BTW, your link is broken.

Comment: Edited the original question

Comment: Do you have your toolchain `bin` directory in the PATH ?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying `cflags` as follows in your `configure` invocation:

```
--cflags="-DOPENSSL_USE_DEPRECATED -nostdinc -nostdinc++"
```